# ng-disable doesn’t work using angular-ui

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui

```html
<h3 class="pulse-green-text"><span class="icon ico_pulse_download"></span>VPN Certificate</h3>
<div class="vpn-cert" ng-controller="vpnController vpnCert">
  <form method="post" name="userform" class="form-horizontal" id="user" ng-submit="save(userform)" novalidate>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group" ng-disabled="true">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Download</label>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pull-left">
            <label class="control-label">Click the link to download </label>
            <a href="/api/download"> certificate</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Renew</label>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pull-left">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Renew the certificate</label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="vpnCert.renew();">
              RENEW
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your posts. This is not your first question. If not for the editor who noticed that your question had code that was not formatted correctly, you would have been mistaken for a spammer which would have had serious implications for your account.

Comment: So, what exactly are you looking for? Looking at `ng-disabled="true"` it should *always* be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

ng-disabled will only work on specific elements like button, input, select etc. 
You can read more about ng-disabled in the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Please provide more information to your question to get a better answer